# Does angularui+bootstrap use js for animations

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Does angularui+bootstrap use js for animations? Or does it utilize css animations?

I can't seem to find documentation about the principles behind it. jQuery for example uses (afaiac) js to create animations which uses cpu and not the gpu.

Answer (score 0):

Both uses CSS3 animation (webkit)
If anybody wants to explain further please go on. I too want to read more.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by saying `angularui+bootstrap`.  Angular UI is mostly categories of vastly different angular ui libraries.

If you're using Angular and Bootstrap, I would strongly encourage you to use [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap).